# Matlab Anfis More than one output?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, matlab, fuzzy-logic

Can Anfis (Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference Systems) in Matlab can have more than one output?

By the way , is it a good idea to use Anfis to decide to ON/OFF fan and lights ?

acording to the example in [matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp715dup12.html) , I can see there is one output only. But it didn't mention it. Anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about it, but couldn't you just have a unique network for each output?

Arguably, each output could be determined independently of the others, couldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned  here 
 (http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_generate_multiple_output_for_ANFIS2) anfis just supports one output which is the last column of train data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this. anfis_input = `*[input1 input2 [output1 output2]?*`